# Ivy: How to set cache policy for SNAPSHOT dependencies?

Tags: ivy

I'm using Ivy Ant and would like to create a policy such that the build checks for the most recent update to a dependency on every build. This is because we're developing in partnership and want to immediately see changes pushed up to the Nexus server.

In Ant I'm doing...

```
    <ivy:cachefileset organisation="com.FOO.storage" conf="default" module="yoda-ui"
                  revision="0.1.8-SNAPSHOT" setid="ac" inline="true"/>
```

In ivy-settings.xml I'm trying...

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="XXX"/>
    ....   
    <caches>
        <cache name="mycache"  basedir="c:/tmp">
            <ttl organisation="com.FOO.storage" module="yoda-ui" duration="0ms"/>
        </cache>
    </caches>
</ivysettings>
```

However, it still appears to not be checking each time

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      default     |   2   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   2   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I believe this is telling me that its not checking the server each time.

So how do I force Ivy to check the server for updates on every build for this particular module?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed your complete ivy settings file. I suspect you're not using the [ibilio resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html):

```
<ibiblio name="mavenrepo" m2compatible="true" root="https://hostname/path/to/repo"/>
```

No need for special cache configuration,
when you enable the **m2compatible** flag which understands how to download snapshots properly.

See the following answer for more details:

- [What's wrong with this Ivy changingPattern / SNAPSHOT configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445268/whats-wrong-with-this-ivy-changingpattern-snapshot-configuration/14445694#14445694)