# Ivy project can't get the latest Maven snapshot (with assembly plugin)

Tags: maven, ivy

When a Ivy project depends a maven project (using assembly plugin), there will be problems. For example:

1. Maven project:
   Suppose the maven project will deploy 2 snapshot packages: for exmaple, one is my-app-1.0.0-20130504.000602-1.jar and the other is my-app-1.0.0-20130504.001348-1-myzip.zip. The pom.xml is shown below.

   ```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <... ...>

   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <descriptors>
             <descriptor>src/main/assembly.xml</descriptor>
           </descriptors>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>make-assembly</id>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>single</goal>
             </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.7</version>
         <configuration>
           <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
           <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
           <version>${project.version}</version>
           <packaging>zip</packaging>
           <file>my-app-1.01-myzip.zip</file>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>

   </project>
   ```
2. The Ivy project

   The Ivy project depends on the 2 artifacts published by above maven project. The ivy.xml is shown below:

   > ```
   > <configurations>
   >   <conf name="get-maven" />
   > </configurations>      
   > <dependencies>
   >   <dependency org="com.mycompany.app" name="my-app" rev="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" changing="true" conf="get-maven->default">
   >     <artifact  name="my-app" ext="jar" type="jar"></artifact> 
   >     <artifact  name="my-app" ext="zip" type="zip" m:classifier="myzip"></artifact>  
   >   </dependency>
   > </dependencies>
   > ```

Issues:
Each time when the maven project deploy new snapshot to the artifactory server, the ivy project can retrieve the latest my-app-xxx.jar from the artifacory server but it can't retrieve the latest my-app-xxx-myzip.zip (ivy can't get to know that the zip is updated and just retrieve the zip from local cache).
What I have to do is to delete the local cache, and run the ivy project again.

I did some investigation, and found the ivy task "convertpom" didn't convert the app-xxx-myzip.zip from pom to ivy, and only 1 artifact (the my-app-xxx.jar) can be found in the converted ivy.xml. Not sure if this is the root cause.

Can anyone help on this? How can I get the lastet snapshots for both artifacts in ivy project?

Regards,
Alben

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify, you're attempting to configure ivy to pull down a snapshot dependency published by a Maven project?

In that case, the following answer will help to explain:

- [What's wrong with this Ivy changingPattern / SNAPSHOT configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445268/whats-wrong-with-this-ivy-changingpattern-snapshot-configuration/14445694#14445694)