# Hierarchy and distribution of tasks among Ant build files in Java EE application from the JUnit unit tests perspective

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have the following hierarchy in of the Ant build files in my application :

```
Application
|---MainProject
|       |__ build.xml
|
|---Project1
|       |__ build.xml
|
|---Project2
       |__ build.xml
```

The Ant targets, based on their tasks are distributed as follows:

1) MainProject build file gives `ant` calls to the `clean` target of all the other build files

2) The JUnit tests in all the projects are executed in the MainProject build file using a common junit target with junit tasks inside it.

3) All other tasks in the other build files are executed through `ant` calls to the `build-project` target in all other files.

4) The build-project target further decides the tasks to be carried out in individual files respectively.

How does this architecture look to you? What would be your approach for such a scenario? What is the recommended way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a fairly typical multi-module build scenario in ANT which, over time, leads to fairly typical large monolithic project builds....

What I'd suggest is consider how Maven structures it's multi-module projects. You want to simulate Maven's concept of a "local repostory" a place where each module pushes its built artifacts. Never share classpaths, instead each "build.xml" file creates them based on files in the local repo:

```
<path id="compile.path">
    <fileset dir="${local.repo.containing.built.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${dir.containing.third.party.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

The benefits

- Each sub-module can be built in a stand-alone fashion (during development) without forcing a complete rebuild of the entire project.
- Your 3rd party dependencies are clearly differientiated within your classpath

As your project grows you'll need to be conscious of interdependencies between modules. With a small number of submodules the build order is obvious, but as time passes, a sub-module may become dependent on lots of other sub-modules being built first.

Finally, the [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) project provides the tooling to add Maven-like features into your ANT build. There is a [multi-module](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/multiproject.html) example, however, I found it difficult to understand as a beginner. I would put it onto your backlog and consider publishing sub-module artifacts into a Maven repository like Nexus in the future. This would make your ANT build compatible with other teams using alternative build technologies like Maven and Gradle.

## Update

- [ivy simple shared repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106143/ivy-simple-shared-repository/4110220#4110220)