# I want to create a Java project that utilizes AND creates smaller sub-projects (libraries), is Apache Ant the proper software to use for this?

Tags: java, ant

Say I was to write a server in Java, the term server is first used to address many subsystems that also serve (multiple actual servers) under one general *server*.

So when I start the main server, it will go through and find all the sub servers registered and start them too as part of the suite.

This means I need to be able to write multiple projects in Eclipse and have them linked to each other so project B can use project A (and vice versa), exactly as if I was to import a jar/library into my build path. But the problem is, I don't know how to do this without actually have multiple projects and then every time I make a change rebuild the jar manually and have the other projects include it.

Is Apache Ant or some similar software what I want?

Comment: You definitely ***do not*** want to create circular dependencies between your projects. That is generally speaking, a design smell and a maintenance/build nightmare.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258851/hierarchy-and-distribution-of-tasks-among-ant-build-files-in-java-ee-application/14268365#14268365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a project management tool that supports dependency management. You can use `ant`, `maven` or `gradle` etc. While I won't start a war of ant vs maven, `maven` is much more than just a build tool and that may help you in future.

Answer (score 0):

Others are with Maven, I am with ANT, it is like religion... none of that is better than other, has advantages and disadvantages each one, and take a decisions it is subjective. Until is my decision, I am using ANT, until my manager or my client mostly they want Maven.

For small sub-projects it is perfect the Ant, I would recommend Maven for bigger one.

Comment: Maven and ANT are far too different for it's zealots to compromise :-) I say this as a reformed ANT zealot, who now uses both technologies. I'd high recommend investigating the introduction of ivy into your ANT builds. It will enable legacy builds to bridge the divide and take advantage of dependency management and large repositories like Maven Central.