# exclude local projects from ivy retrieve

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I have a multimodule ant+ivy project. Dependencies between projects are recorded in ivy.xml files.

When `<ivy:retrieve>` is invoked it will try to download all dependencies including local projects.

How can I exclude my local projects from retrieval ?

Or maybe it's somehow possible to use Filesystem resolver such that it will resolve to `${projects.dir}/*/ivy.xml`, kind of like IvyDE does with workspace resolver.

**UPDATE**

I want to exclude *only* local projects, but still retrieve their transitive dependencies.
I need to duplicate behavior of IvyDE workspace resolver but outside of eclipse.

**EXAMPLE**

Given project structure:

- projects/

  - local.module1/

    - bin/
    - lib/
    - build.xml
    - ivy.xml

      - `<dependency org="local" name="local.module2" />`
  - local.module2/

    - bin/
    - lib/
    - build.xml
    - ivy.xml

      - `<dependency org="external" name="library1" />`
  - common.xml
  - build.xml

I want `local.module1` to be able to retrieve all it's transitive dependencies (local.module2, external.library1) except local projects (local.module2), so effectively this leaves `external.library1`.

From this I want to construct build classpath that consists of direct references to local projects and jar references to external libraries. In case of module1:

- ../local.module2/bin
- lib/external.library1-1.0.jar

In case anyone wonders why - I'm trying to fit ivy into existing build system with minimal changes.

Comment: David W. answer will address the question posed.... but I wonder if your problem is a bit deeper... Just in case it is, I would suggest learning about ivy's configuration mechanism for controlling groups of dependencies. If the build artifacts produced locally are part of a "local" configuration it is then trivial to separate them (ivy retrieve task supports configurations). In conclusion configurations are confusing at first but massively powerful.

Comment: I've tried moving local projects to different configuration but it excluded them completely  with their transitive dependencies.

Comment: Very difficult to comment without a concrete example...

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Multi-module builds are not fun (in ANT or Maven)... before digging in does each module publish it's jar into a repository? See the following for an explanation (and doco links):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106143/ivy-simple-shared-repository/4110220#4110220

Answer (score 0):

In your `ivy.xml` file, add [exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/exclude.html) entities.

```
<dependency org="com.vegicorp"   name="flubaster"    
    conf="compile->default"   rev="3.3">
    <exclude org="com.local"/>
</dependency
```

This will prevent you from downloading anything from 'com.local' or whatever you called your organization when storing your local jars.

(Unless you're talking about the jars for this particular project, and if that's the case, they shouldn't be in your `ivy.xml` file at all).

Comment: Local projects have immediate dependencies on other local projects and `<dependency org="local" name="foo"><exclude org="local">` does not work.

Comment: I see. you want `foo`, but not it's dependencies? Use `conf="provided->master"` as your configuration. Mapping to `master` will not pull dependencies.

Comment: I don't want `foo` but want its dependencies.

Comment: This is going to be very tricky. You can't resolve a jar and not include that jar. However, there may be a work around. When a classpath is resolved, it takes the first class in the first jar it can find. You could munge your classpath to put the freshly built  `local2.jar` from your `local2` project in front of your classpath. Now, when classes are resolved, it will be taken from your freshly build `local` and not from the one from your repository. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced the same problem of partial ivy integration into legacy project just for fetching some transitive dependencies from the maven world while retaining existing build process with ant. Also had to avoid project modules publishing with ivy by using fake local filesystem resolver resolving to dummy jar.

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default">
        <property name="local.maven2.dir" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/" override="false"/>
        <property name="local-project.cache.dir" value="${ivy.settings.dir}/cache" override="false"/>
    </settings>
    <caches resolutionCacheDir="${local-project.cache.dir}" lockStrategy="artifact-lock" useOrigin="true">
        <cache name="local-project" basedir="${local-project.cache.dir}" useOrigin="true"/>
    </caches>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="default">
            <filesystem name="local-maven-2" m2compatible="true" checkmodified="true" changingPattern=".*SNAPSHOT">
                <artifact pattern="${local.maven2.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].[ext]"/>
                <ivy pattern="${local.maven2.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].pom"/>
            </filesystem>
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"
                     root="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"/>
        </chain>
        <filesystem name="local-project" force="true" checkmodified="true" changingPattern=".*" cache="local-project">
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/dummy.jar"/>
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/[module]-ivy.xml"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="example.com" resolver="local-project"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Had to exclude dummy jars from ant as failed to find better approach with ivy:

```
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dependency.export.dir}/[conf]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" type="jar,bundle"/>
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="${dependency.export.dir}">
            <include name="**/*@local-project.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </delete>
```

Still struggling to find a convenient way to [exclude provided dependencies with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227004/how-to-subtract-ivy-dependency-sets).

If someone interested in sample project source, it can be found in [IVY-1443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1443) bug attachment.