# Resolve ivy dependencies from another project in build.xml

Tags: java, ant, ivy

*Disclaimer: I am a newbie using Ant + Ivy*

I have the following eclipse configuration :

**ProjectA**  depends on **ProjectB** and **ProjectC**

**ProjectB**  depends on **ProjectC**

Each project has its owns ivy.xml file.

ProjectA has a build.xml file like this:

```
(...)

<ivy:resolve file="../ProjectC/ivy.xml" />
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.deps.default" conf="default" />
<ivy:cachefileset setid="ivy.deps.default.fileset" conf="default"/>


<ivy:resolve file="../ProjectB/ivy.xml" />
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.deps.default" conf="default" />
<ivy:cachefileset setid="ivy.deps.default.fileset" conf="default"/>


<ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" />
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.deps.default" conf="default" />
<ivy:cachefileset setid="ivy.deps.default.fileset" conf="default"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${webroot}/WEB-INF/lib" erroronmissingdir="no">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${libraries}" erroronmissingdir="no">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <path refid="ivy.deps.default"/>
</path>

    (...)

<javac destdir="c:/abc" includeantruntime="yes" classpathref="ivy.deps.default">
                        <src path="../ProjectC/src"/>
                        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
                    </javac>

 (... Compile ProjectB ...)
 (... Compile ProjectA ...)
```

So, running this build.xml results in error, saying that ProjectC could not compile because it was missing a *.jar file that should have been resolved by ivy:resolve command.

My question is:

- How do I make a build.xml that automatically retrieve the dependencies from child projects and also compile all child projects?

Comment: I would recommend keeping each project separate with its own ivy file. Let each project be standalone and publish its jar into a shared repository rather than attempting to resolve dependencies in another project. Finally for a multi-module project you can use the ivy buildlist task to build each module in the correct order based on interdependencies documented in each module's ivy file.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106143/ivy-simple-shared-repository/4110220#4110220

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an ivy file for each project, but you do not have a build file for each project.  As Mark said in the above comment, each project should build individually.

For example:

- Build ProjectB to a directory like "SharedLibrary" on your drive.  (Nice little JAR file)

  - Take note of ProjectB's IVY file.  It sets the org, artifact name, version, etc
- Add the "SharedLibrary" to your ivy `<resolvers>` list so that IVY looks for dependencies there
- Add the ProjectB as a dependency of ProjectA (Using the noted information from ProjectB's ivy)

That should get you off to the races!

*Pro Tip: instead of a "SharedLibrary" directory, consider using something like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti) to manage the artifacts and pull from there instead.*